# Check block visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, window

We have code like:

```
<body>
<div class="blocks">some text here</div>
<div class="end"></div>
</body>
```

Text can fit in current browser visible part or not.

How to detect, does the block is in visible part of browser window?

I mean, if resoution is 1024x768 and `.block` height bigger than 768, then `.end` is invisible.

- we should detect this on window.ready and also on browser window change.
- if block is visible, then run some function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you need to detect if the entire element is in view or just the top or the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/7Zrdb/2/):

```
$.fn.viewport = (function() {
    var vp = function(el, opts){
        this.el = $(el);
        this.opts = opts;
        this.bind();    // bind resize and scroll
        this.change();  // init change
    };
    vp.prototype = {
        bind: function(){
            $(window).bind('resize scroll', 
                           $.proxy(this.change, this));
        },
        change: function(e){
            var p = this.el.position(),
                o = this.el.offset(),
                d = { w: this.el.width() +o.left, h: this.el.height()+o.top },
                win = $(window),
                winD = {w:win.width() + win.scrollLeft(), h:win.height()+win.scrollTop()};

            if(d.w <= winD.w && d.h <= winD.h){
                console.log('inview');   
            } else {
                console.log('out of view');
                this.opts.outOfView.call(this);
            }
        }
    };
    return function(opts){
        return $(this).each(function(){
           $(this).data('vp', new vp(this, opts)); 
        });
    };
})();
```

And use like this:

```
$('#el').viewport({
    outOfView: function(){
        alert('out of view');
    }   
});
```

Comment: This does not work for out of scroll (even if we add the scroll checks). You are only taking care of the element width while in fact you have to take into account offset left and offset top values.

Comment: Thanks and Good job. My version > http://jsfiddle.net/hPjbh/ though your is more structured.

Answer (score 1):

First grab the window dimensions.

```
var windowSize = {width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()};
```

Next grab the div position in relation to the document:

```
var position = $('.block').offset()
```

Then make your if's:

```
if(position.top > windowSize.height){ /* here we go */ }
```

You might want to also grab div dimensions in case there is a possibility it will be out of bounds on the top or left side.

You could make it into a function that returns a boolean value and then call it on the window.resize and document.ready events.

**EDIT:** Added scrollTop to account for scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

As a quick answer you'll have to do some computation on load (psuedocode assumes jQuery).

1. Find the window height $(window).outerHeight(true)
2. Find the offset of the ".end" element $(".end").offset()
3. Find the scroll distance of the window $(window).scrollTop()
4. Calculate! It should roughly be:

   if ((step1 + step3) > step2) {
       //do stuff here
   }

Note that that does not check if you are scrolled past the ".end" element. I didn't verify this one, so hopefully I'm not missing something big.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the offsetTop and offsetLeft attributes of the element
2. Get the width of the element in question
3. Get the width of screen
4. Do the relevant maths and see if the element is in the viewport or now.

in jQuery you can do something like

`$("#element").attr("offsetTop")`

**EDIT:**
Simple and Effective: http://jsfiddle.net/hPjbh/

Comment: Good answer. Also, you can do `$("#element").offset().top`.